# How to convert pyspark row to class?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below,

```
df=spark.sql('select * from <table_name>')

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  Name    | Max   |  Name   | Avg   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  pouser1 | 1.0   |  2.0    | 3.0   |
|  pouser2 | 1.0   |  2.0    | 3.0   |
|  pouser3 | 1.0   |  2.0    | 3.0   |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
```

I have a class with below definition,

```
class pouser:

  @property
  def name():
     return self.__name

  @property
  def max():
     return self.__max

  @property
  def min():
     return self.__min

  @property
  def avg():
     return self.__avg
```

Is it possible to transform dataframe to list of `pouser` objects?

Comment: not sure to understand what you want to achieve. Can you show the expected output of the `pousser` object  and its methods ? how do you plan on using it ?

Comment: I would like to have a list of pouser. For example `[pouser(1,2,3), pouser(1,2,3),pouser(1,2,3)].`. I am expecting a typecast similar to Scala so the consuming code is not aware of any dataframe but calls `pouser.max` to get their max.

Comment: could you please add what you tried and what is blocking you ? any error  ?

Comment: could you please tell me self.__max refers to what value?? 

as there is no constructor in class definition. Try to share what you want to achieve here with output as example

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible (but is it really a use case for spark - maybe not).

Spark is a big data processing tool, where you can manipulate large data that cannot fit the computer memory. Your current example exactly does the opposite, trying to fit this data into computer memory in form of objects.

So if you still want to do that using spark you can collect the data into memory by using `df.toPandas()` and then create objects from there by iterating through the rows.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that is not the usecase of Spark. Actually, I simplified my example select query but what I am after is the aggregate of huge data. So, I wanted to store the aggregate on a class object

Comment: Generally aggregated information is not so huge that will not fit in memory. Therefore, as I wrote, you can bring the agg information to local memory using `toPandas()` or `collect()`